# How to skip to 86th occurrence in a CSV file using vim

Tags: bash, shell, unix, vim

I have a CSV file open in vim with 4 rows.
How to I jump to the 86th occurrence in a row?

Comment: 86th occurrence of what? of a search pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're searching for a letter `R`:

```
86/R<Enter>
```